# Video hosting service with custom subdomain

Tags: video, content-filter

On our website we want to have a link to a short video, couple of minutes long.  We don't want to host it on our own server due to our slow upload speed & also we want it seachable on a YouTube style service.  We're figuring as well we'll get more hits on it from YouTube.

The problem is our content filter currently blocks all video websites.  If I unblock www.youtube.com so the video can be uploaded and viewed from within the the company network, then that grants access for everyone within the company access to all of youtube.

But I can unblock subdomains, so if a video hosting service allowed me to setup under a subdomain such as mycompany.youtube.com that would allow me to unblock just our video.  I've setup an account on youtube and it does not appear this is an option with them.  I'm hoping there are other services I'm not aware of that may offer this.

Alternately, any other ideas for how I can do this?  If I can't find anything then I'll likely do one copy of the video on the internal intranet site & have the person upload the one to YouTube from home.

Comment: I am confused by your question - are you looking for some solution on youtube.com, or looking to set up your own video hosting solution?

Comment: I reworked the question, hopefully this makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any sites that operate in this manner, and if you need one to you might have to create your own site to include your video content on instead.

If your blocking facility allows partial matching against a full URL (there than being purely host name based) and you know the IDs of the permitted video content you could add rules to allow just those videos (i.e. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YourVidCodeHere).

Other solutions are possible using proxy servers, but at that point you may as well go the whole hog and setup your own web server for the videos anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a bit late, but we are also looking for a similar solution. Although we were not able to find anyone that provides free video hosting while providing subdomain capability. We did find that Vimeo PRO allow you to configured a subdomain of your choice to host your own videos.

Following is the instruction on their FAQ on how to set it up.
http://vimeo.com/help/faq/pro#custom_domain